# how can fixed width & height percentage when I using 'a href'?

Tags: html, href

how can fixed width & height percentage when I using 'a href' ?

This is my code, but when I using a href to img, I cannot ixed width & height percentage, so how can I do?

how can fixed width & height percentage when I using 'a href' ?

I have tried this method, but still can't

```
<div class="card-deck" >
            @forelse($blogs as $blog)
                <div class="card mb-4" >
                    <a href="blog/{{ $blog->id }}"><img src="{{ $blog->image_url }}" class="card-img-top" alt="{{ $blog->title }}" width="90%" height="80%"></a>
                    <div class="card-body" style="width: 500px; height: 200px;">
                        <h5 class="card-title" style="overflow:hidden;display: -webkit-box;-webkit-line-clamp:2;-webkit-box-orient: vertical;white-space: normal;"><a href="blog/{{ $blog->id }}">{{ $blog->title }}</a></h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
                @if($loop->iteration % 2 == 0)
                    <div class="w-100 d-none d-sm-block d-md-none" style="width: 500px; height: 200px;"><!-- wrap every 2 on sm--></div>
                @endif
                @if($loop->iteration % 3 == 0)
                    <div class="w-100 d-none d-md-block d-lg-none" style="width: 500px; height: 200px;"><!-- wrap every 3 on md--></div>
                @endif
                @if($loop->iteration % 4 == 0)
                    <div class="w-100 d-none d-lg-block d-xl-none" style="width: 500px; height: 200px;"><!-- wrap every 4 on lg--></div>
                @endif
                @if($loop->iteration % 5 == 0)
                    <div class="w-100 d-none d-xl-block" style="width: 500px; height: 200px;"><!-- wrap every 5 on xl--></div>
                @endif
            @endforelse
        </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKQjr.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because `%` values of width and height happens within a parent container or a presentation area available for it.

Ex: If you have

```html
<div style="width: 1000px; height: 1000px;">
  <a href="https://a.com">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="aa" width="50%" height="70%" />
  </a>
</div>
```

So in above case, image width will be `500px` width, since `50%` of 1000px is `500px` and height will be `700px` since `70%` of 1000px is `700px`.

So make sure that you're specifing something `%` value based on it's parent container or presentation area available for it.

Comment: @Stanley updated my answer. Height `%` values also works the same like `width`, just add how much height to assign. If you need exact fixed amount(no matter how much parent div is) then you can use `px` values.

Comment: still can't ...:(

Comment: @Stanley what are you trying to accomplish? there are 2 images - one on left and other on right in your image file.

Comment: https://imgur.com/E0awNYo

Five photo in a column, but can't fixed height